# Java generic method

Tags: java, generics

I want to use generics to register users. Dependant on the type T, I want to decide which Manager to instantiate. Here is what I have so far:

```
private <T extends SharingManager> void registerUsersInManager(List<User> usersToRegister){
    for(User u: usersToRegister){
        registry.put(u, new T(u));
    }
}
```

Eclipse is giving me an error saying that the type T can't be instantiated.

I am not sure whether I just made a syntax error or if I messed up the whole concept. Is it possible to achieve what I want to do with generics?

Comment: You don't instantiate generics, generics are "filled in" object types.

Comment: Check out http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html great resource explaining generics really well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create new instances at runtime, you need to have the Class object, and then create a new instance using a constructor. Construction may fail if the class is an interface, an abstract class, or does not have any visible constructors.

Assuming that your implementations of `SharingManager` have a constructor with a `User` arg, you can change your method to:

```
private <T extends SharingManager> void registerUsersInManager(Class<T> type, List<User> usersToRegister){
    final Constructor<T> constructor = type.getConstructor(User.class);
       for(User u: usersToRegister){
        registry.put(u, constructor.newInstance(u));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`new T(u)`  This is something that you cannot do.

Generics are implemented using [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java. Most generic information are lost at compile time, and you can't know the actual value of T at runtime. This means you simply can't instanciate generic types.

You can write correct as follows

```
private <T extends SharingManager> void registerUsersInManager(List<User> usersToRegister, Class<T> obj){
for(User u: usersToRegister){
    registry.put(u, obj.newInstance());
}
}
```